# PDO fetch and fetchAll with conditional statement not working

Tags: php, pdo, fetch, conditional-statements, fetchall

his is not working can anyone help please?

```
(count($stmt->fetchAll()) > 1) ? $result = $stmt->fetchAll() : $result = $stmt->fetch();

print_r($result);
```

Comment: this is more proper way. `$result  = (count($stmt->fetchAll()) > 1) ? ($stmt->fetchAll()) : ($stmt->fetch());`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this doesn't solves my problem.

Comment: See the answer by Mureinik below. it has reason for why its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the `fetchXYZ` methods advance the underlying cursor, so once you've called them, you cannot "go back" and get the same rows again.

You could redo your condition in-memory, after calling `fetchAll()` only once:

```
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
if (count($result) == 1) {
    $result = $result[0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million Mureinik.